# ContentControl with special border

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, contentcontrol, imagebrush

I want to write a `ContentControl` to host other controls and give them a special border.

So I added a new `UserControl`, made a `ContentControl` of it. It is having a grid, on the outer sides I want to have the border.

**So the first question is: Is this a good approach to achieve a "Bordered" Control?**

Here is the XAML

```
<ContentControl x:Class="DemoApplication.Controls.ImpressedContentControl"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                Name="ImpressedContent"
                d:DesignHeight="300"
                d:DesignWidth="300"
                mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedLeftBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_left.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
            <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedRightBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_right.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
            <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedTopBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_top.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
            <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedBottomBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_bottom.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedTopBrush}" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedBottomBrush}" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedLeftBrush}" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedRightBrush}" />

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Content="{Binding ElementName=ImpressedContent,
                                  Path=ControlContent}" />

    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

In the codebehind I have a `DependencyProperty` to set the content.

```
    public partial class ImpressedContentControl : ContentControl
    {
        public ImpressedContentControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Control ControlContent
        {
            get { return (Control)GetValue(ControlContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ControlContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlContentProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("ControlContent", typeof(Control), typeof(ImpressedContentControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
    }
```

I want to use it somewhat like

```
<controls:ImpressedContentControl Grid.Column="1">
            <ControlContent>
                <TextBlock Text="FooBar Text" />
            </ControlContent>
</controls:ImpressedContentControl>
```

Is it possible to use the Content property of the ContentControl somehow?

Is there an easier way to achieve that?

Any ideas highly appeciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should use WPF control template here. It's very easy to give any control a template that defines its visual appearance.
In your case you can define the template for your `ImpressedContentControl` like this

```
<ContentControl x:Class="DemoApplication.Controls.ImpressedContentControl"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                Name="ImpressedContent"
                d:DesignHeight="300"
                d:DesignWidth="300"
                mc:Ignorable="d">
       <!--define control template-->
      <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedLeftBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_left.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedRightBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_right.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedTopBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_top.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="ImpressedBottomBrush"
                        ImageSource="/DemoApplication;component/Images/Impressed_bottom.png"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,100,100"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedTopBrush}" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedBottomBrush}" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedLeftBrush}" />
                <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Background="{DynamicResource ImpressedRightBrush}" />

                <!--Use ContentPresenter to display inner content-->
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></ContentPresenter>

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </ContentControl.Template>   
    </ContentControl>
```

And use your control like this

```
<controls:ImpressedContentControl Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="FooBar Text" />
</controls:ImpressedContentControl>
```

There is no need for the `ImpressedContent` Dependency property. In fact you could do all of this without even creating new control class, just by using only base `ContentControl` and applying new style to it that uses the below template.

You can find here more about WPF control templates

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx

Comment: this seems to be just what I want. Will try it out.

Comment: Think this is it. Thank you very much! just have to do something about my images ;)